# phpseclib - XAMPP Mac Os

Tags: php, xampp, phpseclib

I'm a beginner developer and I've some issues using phpseclib in order to SSH to an Amazon ec2 VPS that is running a python script.

My main issue is use the phpseclib... I don't have any clue how to "install" the phpseclib on my xmapp server... It seems that including the library files into the project folder ins't enough.. I've read that you have to install it via some command line stuff

Could someone explain me how to do that? Like basic step by step thing.

I'm using Mac OS environment

Thank you!

Comment: try homebrew, its really easy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions for tutorials and guides are off-topic. Please take a look at [tour], [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using "Composer", the most widely used PHP package manager as of today, to take care of including packages.

You should be able to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) via `brew`, or another method described on their site.

Then, make a project directory, and in it execute in your terminal:

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
```

In your PHP Code just `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` - this file should be created by Composer, just include this one file and Composer will take care of autoloading the classes you use at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I've used composer and I got rid of most of my "libraries" problems!